# Java util function for finding max element in unsorted array

Tags: java

Is there any java util class and corresponding method, that returns the max element in an unsorted array ?

Comment: Please explain why you cannot find this on the googles?

Comment: for 1522 of rep, you could have asked in a better manner or did some googling first!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor That 1522 comes all from questions, none from answers.

Comment: @icza : exactly my point in previous comment!! :D

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Collections.max(Arrays.asList(your_array))`. And array cannot be a primitive array.

Java Docs : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection)

PS : I suggest you to go through java docs first before posting question here.

Comment: Might what to add the caveat that the array cannot be a primitive array.

Answer (score 2):

`Collections.max(Collection<YourObj> yourList);`

`YouObj` should implement `Comparable`, or it will just get max by natural ordering...

Answer (score 1):

With the Java 8 Stream api you can do this very easily.

Assuming the array is not primitive:

```
public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(final T[] array) {
    return Stream.of(array).max(naturalOrder()).get();
}
```

This forces the object in the array to implement `Comparable` to itself or some superclass of itself - i.e. it has a "natural order".

With a primitive array, Java 8 has `IntStream`, `LongStream` and `DoubleStream` which can be used like so:

```
public long max(final long[] array) {
    return LongStream.of(array).max().getAsLong();
}
```

Note that both these methods with throw a `NoSuchElementException` if an empty array is passed - this is by design. There is no sensible default to return when finding the `max()` of an empty array and Java 8 therefore returns a `Optional[XXX]` which can be used to determine if a result was calculated.

Comment: Nice answer but don't you think user who posted such question, couldn't understand this :D

Answer (score 0):

If your array is just a int, double or that kind of array you can easily use 
`Collections.max()` method.

```
Collections.max(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Before asking this sort of question please first use google and check if there are already know way to solve your issue. I have copied java api doc for 2 methods here.

**Collections.max()**

```
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll)
```

> **Returns** the maximum element of the given collection, **according to the
>   natural ordering of its elements**. All elements in the collection must
>   implement the Comparable interface. Furthermore, all elements in the
>   collection must be mutually comparable (that is, e1.compareTo(e2) must
>   not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the
>   collection). This method iterates over the entire collection, hence it
>   requires time proportional to the size of the collection.
>
> **Parameters**: coll - the collection whose maximum element is to be
>   determined. Returns: the maximum element of the given collection,
>   according to the natural ordering of its elements.

But if you have some sort of object array that is not directly compare with another element you must go for the overloaded max method which uses `Comparator` parameter as well. Therefore you must have a comparator as well.

```
public static <T> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll,
        Comparator<? super T> comp)
```

> **Returns** the maximum element of the given collection, **according to the
>   order induced by the specified comparator**. All elements in the
>   collection must be mutually comparable by the specified comparator
>   (that is, comp.compare(e1, e2) must not throw a ClassCastException for
>   any elements e1 and e2 in the collection). This method iterates over
>   the entire collection, hence it requires time proportional to the size
>   of the collection.
>
> **Parameters**: coll - the collection whose maximum element is to be
>   determined. comp - the comparator with which to determine the maximum
>   element. A null value indicates that the elements' natural ordering
>   should be used. Returns: the maximum element of the given collection,
>   according to the specified comparator.